# NVIDIA drivers not responding

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I'm having problems using my NVIDIA. I just installed ubuntu for the first time and I tried running some games using Lutris, then after receiving an error about graphics I started digging and ended up with my second monitor not being recognized as well ;)))

I tried running some logs with NVIDIA and I got this:

```
ERROR: Unable to build the NVIDIA kernel module.
ERROR: Unable to build the NVIDIA kernel module.
```

After running other log I got:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

When I saw in System information, ubuntu shows only my Intel interface as well.

If anyone could help me out I would be very very grateful :)

Update: disabling the secure boot on BIOS fixed the monitor problem, but I'm still having trouble with NVIDIA drivers, I tried to "purge" them and reinstall again but I ended up with more errors:

Below I've pasted the error when I tried to install nvidia-driver-460

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-460 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-460 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (= 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The NVIDIA in the software & Updates is a GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]

[picture of the metapackages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaceb.png)

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: Thank you! With that I was able to fix the monitor issue! I will update the question tho :)

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1325147/edit) and add some more info about your system like the version of Ubuntu you are using and what is your hardware.  There is a chance that you might be able to get away with the drivers are that now in the Ubuntu repositories of `nvidia-driver-460`.  The image is really hard to see.  It would be better if you did a copy and paste of the errors into your question.

Comment: Of course, sorry for the image. I pasted now the error ofr that specific driver! Hope it clarify better! Thanks very much

Comment: The 460.67 driver has not been officially released to the Ubuntu repos yet.  It is actually in the Proposed repo which is used for Development.  I would suggest that you turn off the Proposed by going to **Settings -> Software & Updates -> Developer Options** then unselect the "Pre-released updates".   Then do the `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460`.

Comment: I actually don't know where you got the 460.67 as there is no driver release of 460.67-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1 in any of the Ubuntu repositories.  If I am seeing this correctly, you have Ubuntu 20.04, which should be the NVIDIA driver 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1.

Comment: Hello, so I tried doing that, but the Pre-released option was already disabled. I ran the two codes again and reboot my pc. Then my monitor went black again, so I checked the drivers tab on software & updates and it automatically selected the metapackage 450. I tried switching back to 460 and I got an error: pk-client-error-quark nvidia error: installed nvidia-dkms-460-package post-installed script (i will put the image in the comment)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my issue using "purge" to the 460 driver and all nvidia drivers as well. The driver that worked for me was de 450 tho.